# Page does not respond when update panel is in progress, please guide?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

In a page I have multiple update panels that have timers associated with them to refresh the grids. My issue is that when asynchronous request (update panel) is in progress page does not respond. If user try to click some other link to move to some other page he even can not do that until asynchronous request is completed.

Is it not possible that user may able to cl...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser runs in a single-threaded mode, you can’t run any background task. If any task is running all other event gets queued up and user will get a impact that browser is hanged or not responding, so for situation like this you need to handle this by yourself.

1-  Keep the partial post back light and fast.

2-  If possible do it in small steps.

3-  Show the progress bar, so that client will not get irritated.

Answer (score 1):

Only one UpdatePanel can postback at a time.  If your timer is kicking off multiple requests, the last one will win and cancel the rest.

**Workaround:** 
[Simultanious Async Requests Using Multiple Update Panel](http://www.codeproject.com/tips/57035/Simultanious-Async-Requests-Using-Multiple-Update-.aspx)

Comment: thanks rick schott,

does asp.net supports multithreading ? or java script allow it ?

Comment: Yes asp.net supports multithreading but only on the server side.  If you want multiple client side async requests, you should move away from the UpdatePanel and use something like jQuery.ajax().